# decompose color code in react material

Tags: reactjs, colors, material-design, material-ui

I am using react-material and MuiThemeProvider component to use theme.

Here is the code that I copy from the example given below on the website

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: purple, // Purple and green play nicely together.
    secondary: {
      ...green,
      A400: '#00e677',
    },
    error: red,
  },
});
```

when I changed in the above code `primary:'#2ab667'` like this it gives an error

[image]

So, I don't know where I did wrong or how to use any color code rather using specific color from material

Answer (score 2):

It seems the values must be objects. Try giving like what you did for `secondary`, defining primary as an object:

```
primary: {
  50: '#f3e5f5',    // replace or delete all colors as you wish
  100: '#e1bee7',
  200: '#ce93d8',
  300: '#ba68c8',
  400: '#ab47bc',
  500: '#9c27b0',
  600: '#8e24aa',
  700: '#7b1fa2',
  800: '#6a1b9a',
  900: '#4a148c',
  A100: '#ea80fc',
  A200: '#e040fb',
  A400: '#d500f9',
  A700: '#aa00ff',
  contrastDefaultColor: 'light',
};
```

or to reuse purple with certain shades changed:

```
primary: {
  ...purple,
  A700: '#aa00ff',
};
```

**UPDATE** In your case, you could use a snippet like this (I've used your color code #2ab667 for A400 an different shades of that in other keys):

```
primary: {
  A100: '#ADF9CE',
  A200: '#5EE599',
  A400: '#2ab667',
  A700: '#188146',
  contrastDefaultColor: 'light'
},
secondary: ...
```

Comment: I use like primary: {
  ...purple,
  A700: '#aa00ff',
}; but it use purple code not this

Comment: changing just one shade won't make a difference. _And_ A700 **is** `#aa00ff` inside purple. You can see the difference if you change all shades and define your own primary color, like my first snippet.

Comment: So it means that if I want to use any color then I need to write my own properties of color?

Comment: Is it possible to put any color code for primary in createMuiTheme constant ?

Comment: in mui, a color is composed of shades `50....A700`, `A700` and `900` being the darkest; see https://www.muicss.com/docs/v1/getting-started/colors. You can use a hex code inside an object, assign it to keys like `400` or `500` to see a difference. Remove the `...purple` so that only your codes are used. In general, it's better you define hex values for all shades from `50` to `A700`, or atleast values `A100` to `A700`

Comment: Can you please write a code snippet here to use hex code inside an object ?

Comment: Thanks but still there is issue, if I define 500: '#f5f5f5' is working not other shades as you define A100, A200 are not working. I define all the shaded as you mentioned on the top but it only pick 500 shade. So how to use different shades ?

Comment: Maybe the theme doesn't use other shades.. See https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/d7ee3b927d33d63f1d642438e4d423927cb86bf0/src/colors to see how they have designed their colors. You wanted to use a hex value, and when you got it, you want shades !! Maybe the theme uses only the value at 500..

Answer (score 0):

```
palette: {
    primary: purple
```

The above means "Primary **color** of the palette is `purple`".
`purple` **color** has pre-defined set of **hues**(or shades) within that, ranging from `#F3E5F5` to `#AA00FF`.
Your favorite `#2ab667` is a **hue** and NOT a **color**.

If you wish to make 'all your *primary* tagged components take the shade `#2ab667`',

something like this:

[image]

`<Button raised color="primary">Primary</Button>`

approach as suggested by [Dane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6473435/dane) above